# Default mock for specific type in NSubstitute

Tags: c#, nsubstitute

Is there a way to specify a return object for every method and property of specific type?

For example I want all method, that returns string, return `"TestString"` instead of `null`.

Usually, I have to write something like this:

```cs
        public interface ISomeInterface
        {
            string GetValue();
            
        }

        public void Test()
        {
            var mock1 = Substitute.For<ISomeInterface>();
            mock1.GetValue().Returns("TestString");
            var mock2 = Substitute.For<ISomeInterface>();
            mock2.GetValue().Returns("TestString");
            
            // ... test something
        }
```

But is there a way to specify that all created `ISomeInterface` substutes will return `"TestString"` for `GetValue()` method?

PS. There is an issue at NSubstitute github, where I've asked the same question with more specific details. https://github.com/nsubstitute/NSubstitute/issues/751

Comment: Why do you need more than one substitute version of the same interface?  When would you need to use Mock2 that you couldn't use Mock1 instead?

Comment: The case I want to cover is to substitute *every* `string`. It could be used in lots of interfaces at lots of tests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is written here - https://github.com/nsubstitute/NSubstitute/issues/751.

Long story short, you have to implement `IAutoValueProvider` and `IAutoValueProviderFactory` for your type. For this specific case it could look like this:

```cs
    
// run this one time before all of your tests
...
var customizedContainer = NSubstituteDefaultFactory.DefaultContainer.Customize();
customizedContainer.Decorate<IAutoValueProvidersFactory>((factory, _) => new StringValueProviderFactory(factory));
SubstitutionContext.Current = customizedContainer.Resolve<ISubstitutionContext>();
...    

public class StringValueProviderFactory : IAutoValueProvidersFactory
{
    private readonly IAutoValueProvidersFactory _original;

    private class StringValueProvider : IAutoValueProvider
    {
        public bool CanProvideValueFor(Type type)
        {
            return type == typeof(string);
        }

        public object GetValue(Type type)
        {
            if (type == typeof(string))
                return "TestString";
            throw new InvalidOperationException($"Can not create string for type {type.Name}");
        }
    }

    public StringValueProviderFactory(IAutoValueProvidersFactory original)
    {
        _original = original;
    }
    
    public IReadOnlyCollection<IAutoValueProvider> CreateProviders(ISubstituteFactory substituteFactory)
    {
        return new [] {new StringValueProvider()}.Concat(_original.CreateProviders(substituteFactory)).ToArray();
    }
}
```